# Having trouble inserting values into a database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, web

I am trying to insert these values to my database but i am having some issues with it. i am not sure why. below are the values that need to be inserted and the current code i have written for this is below.

```
<?php
include ('db.php');

$cfname=$_POST['c_firstname']
$clname=$_POST['c_lastname'];
$address=$_POST['c_address'];
$postcode=$_POST['c_postcode'];
$mobno=$_POST['c_mobno'];
$emailad=$_POST['c_email'];
$expsttime=$_POST['e_sttime'];
$expendtime=$_POST['e_endtime'];
$expname=$_POST['experience'];
$car1=$_POST['car'];
$driver1=$_POST['driver'];
$host1=$_POST['host'];




$addnewbookingSQL="INSERT into experienceBooking 
(firstName, lastName, address, postcode, mobNo, emailAd, expStTime, expEndTime, experienceName, car, driver, host)
values ('".$cfname."','".$clname."','".$address."','".$postcode."','".$mobno."','".$emailad."','".$expsttime."','".$expendtime."','".$expname."','".$car1."','".$driver1."','".$host1."')";
$exeaddnewbookingSQL=mysql_query($addnewbookingSQL);



?>
```

i am not sure if my  SQL query it right as it is displaying a blank screen when this code is performed.

Comment: Blank screen usually means syntax errors. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. You've enough to debug your code and find out why/where it's failing.

Comment: Run or fail, there's nothing in here that would generate output to the screen.

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html). You're also in danger of allowing [SQL Injection.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: You still didn't take me up on [my first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110356/need-to-create-a-forget-password-functionality-in-php-mysql#comment44594581_28110356) under your other question yet http://stackoverflow.com/q/28110356/ - They just never listen, *eh Sam?* - @JayBlanchard then they ask themselves *"where'd my DB go?"*. Will they ever learn; doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you provided, you have a syntax error; you're missing a `;` after `$cfname=$_POST['c_firstname']`.

---

However, you are using [deprecated functions](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) and should discontinue their use. I recommend using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), however since you seem to be most familiar with the `mysql_` functions, I have provided you with a solution using the newer `mysqli_*` functions and [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) below.

```
// Connect to database
$connection = new mysqli('server', 'user', 'password', 'db');

// Check connection for error
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

// Prepare the insert
$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO experienceBooking (firstName, lastName, address, postcode, mobNo, emailAd, expStTime, expEndTime, experienceName, car, driver, host) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

// Bind values
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssss', $_POST['c_firstname'], $_POST['c_lastname'], $_POST['c_address'], $_POST['c_postcode'], $_POST['c_mobno'], $_POST['c_email'], $_POST['e_sttime'], $_POST['e_endtime'], $_POST['experience'], $_POST['car'], $_POST['driver'], $_POST['host']);

// Execute prepared statement
$stmt->execute();

// Close statement and connection
$stmt->close();
$connection->close();
```

Comment: Best to "prepare" for the worse ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semi-colon on the 4th line:

```
$cfname=$_POST['c_firstname'];
```

---

## Tip:

I always add the following at the top of my php scripts while coding:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

The above will help you to debug your code, specifically, get the lines that have errors.
Comment when in production mode.

Comment: better tip is to put those directives in php.ini, so they'll ALWAYS be active. they should never be off on a devel/debug system. putting them at the top of the script won't help if there's a fatal parse error that prevents the script from running. no script, no directives, no error output.

Comment: @MarcB Good point. However, how many times have we seen where OP's don't have access to that system file; *what then?*

Comment: crawl back into bed and pull the covers up over your face...?

Comment: Yeah, that'd be better. Best to protect against incoming storms @MarcB

Comment: @MarcB "should never be off on a devel/debug system" I cannot agree with you. Imagine that, for some reason, there's a problem with the script in the future, users will have access to precious information about the system, specifically, paths.

Comment: You have to be smart about it @PedroLobito and trap errors while returning something nice to the user. We leave error checking in and on all the time and always encourage our devs to fix errors as they go while adding them to the error handler.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Agreed, error checking always `on`, not  `ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Answer (score 0):

Well you are not terminating with the semicolon in the 4th line..

Additionally you should modify the code like this.

```
$addnewbookingSQL="INSERT into experienceBooking values ('".mysql_real_escape_string($cfname)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($clname)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($address)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($postcode.)"','".mysql_real_escape_string($mobno)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($ mailad)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($expsttime)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($expendtime)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($expname)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($car1)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($driver1)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($host1)."')";
if($exeaddnewbookingSQL=mysql_query($addnewbookingSQL));

else
    echo mysql_error();
```

Where in above code `mysql_real_escape_string` is for protecting from the sql injection and `mysql_error` is for the case if you had any error in the query.